# Angularjs material date picker, show 18 years before dates only

Tags: angularjs

I have following text input filled by model value in timestamp:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="ln.dateofbirth" md-current-view="year" md-date-filter="ctrl.dateOfBirth" md-max-date="maxDate" md-placeholder="Date Of Birth" required></md-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup minDate and maxDate on init method.

**controller**

```
var minDate = new Date(Date.now());
var maxDate = new Date(Date.now());
var startDate = maxDate;

// setting the min date and thus the max birth date allowing < 100 year old choosable birthdate
this.minDate.setDate( this.minDate.getDate() );
this.minDate.setFullYear( this.minDate.getFullYear() - 100 );

// setting the calendar's start date and youngest birth dates for > 18 years old
this.maxDate.setDate( this.maxDate.getDate() );
this.maxDate.setFullYear( this.maxDate.getFullYear() - 18 );
this.startDate = this.maxDate;
```

**View**

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="ln.dateofbirth" md-current-view="year" md-date-filter="ctrl.dateOfBirth" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate" md-placeholder="Date Of Birth" required></md-datepicker>
```

Check [mdDatepicker API Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker) for more detail.